# How do I add style to a react element within the return function?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to add style to an element in my return of a react component, but I want to achieve this without adding a class. My text editor auto fills a style option, but I believe the syntax is wrong, since when trying to add a function on an onClick event, its a little different when its in the return of a react element. For example, instead of
`onClick=function()`
its
`onClick={() => {function()}}`
I'm hoping that instead of `style={"background-color: green;"}` its a different syntax to actually allow style changes once it hits the dom.

Comment: kindly provide some code and also what is it that you want to return style in the onClick and not in the style ?

Answer (score 1):

In-line styles can be done, and here is a code example as you have not provided one.

for example, lets inline style an h1 tag

```
<h1 style={{background-color:'green', color:'white'}}>This is a tilte</h1>
```

more can be found here

additionally, I would not recommend inline styling as it's not industry-standard and can cause your code to become bloted.

Comment: it's actually backgroundColor not background-color, because you implement a styling object not css property

Answer (score 0):

Style tags in react can indeed contain a references to functions.

I am not fully sure if you are working with React component classes or component functions, but your syntax can besides as follows. Create a variable called `customStyle` which will contain a function that returns your required style object:

```
customStyle = () => { return { color: 'red' } };
```

You can then reference `customStyle` inside markup as follows:

```
<div style={this.customStyle()}>My Element</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

idont know if i understood your question well, You can achieve what you want by making a style state, then mutate it whatever style you want with setState

```js
const [style, setStyle] = useState({})

const App = () => {

 return <div style={style}>
 <button onClick={() => setStyle({color: 'red'})}>handler button </button>
 </div>
}
```